# Android - How to find if device is receiving GSM signals or not?

Tags: android, gsm, phone-state-listener, signal-strength

I simply want to check if my device is receiving GSM signals or not. I know about `SignalStrength` class and its `getGsmSignalStrength()`. I have worked with `PhoneStateListener` and `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`.

But even where I am not receiving any signals, I still get greater than 0 GSM signals strength, as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

See the signals level, its not even low, its red crossed. And the `getGsmSignalStrength()` returned me 16. *(Current is a different number, please ignore it.)*

Comment: Do you have a valid SIM on your phone? The red cross may well just represent that your phone was unable to register to any network, even though it is making measurements in the background.

Comment: Yes, my sim works very fine. I am in a specific location where this operator has no service.

Comment: OK. Same effect as not having a valid SIM then. Your phone will first try to register to your home PLMN operator. If it fails it will continue measuring for other alternatives (and this is what you see reported in the measurements), but your phone is restricted by the SIM policy not to register with any other network that shares the same mobile country code (this is why you see "no signal" in the signal bars). National roaming is normally forbidden (with a few exceptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in the GSM signal from your operator then use getMnc() from [CellIdentityGsm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.html) to establish if the signal you are measuring is valid.

If you want the GSM signal only when the device is in service (ie successfully connected to a network) then use the [ServiceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html) checker to establish what state the device is in.

As per above comments, the symptoms indicate that you are measuring other operators' GSM signals.

Comment: You can also find the MNC of your desired network [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code).

Comment: thank you for the response. I'll check it and let you know :)

Comment: So, you are saying that to check if my device is receiving signals I have to check if `getMnc()` is returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` according to [Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.html#getMnc%28%29) ??

Comment: It depends on what you are really after: if you want to measure the GSM so signal only when the device is registered to a network then you need to check what state the device is in. You should use the [in service checker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html) for this. This is better than checking the MNC as the MNC approach assumes that you know the correct MNC. If you do not perform this check then you're just getting device measurements from some arbitrary network while the device is trying to connect to alternate networks in the background.

Comment: Yes, [ServiceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html) is what I was looking for, thank you. Please edit this thing in your answer and I'll mark it as corrected.